# How do I create this output in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this information.

Table OrderTotals

```
Order  Value
A         10
B         20
C         15
```

Table Orderdetails

```
Order  Line Description
A        11 Red
B        24 Blue
B        25 Green
B        28 Yellow
C        17 Green
```

And I want this output

```
Order Line Description Value
A       11 Red         10
B       24 Blue        20
B       25 Green
B       28 Yellow
C       17 Green       15
```

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: This sounds like a problem you should try to solve outside your SQL Server. You want to portray order line details with the order total, but only for the first record of said details. Makes little sense to me other than terribly odd design. To answer your question, it is certainly possible though. If you use `ROW_NUMBER()` sorted on your `Line` and use a `CASE WHEN` if it's 1 to only then select the order total with a subquery you'd get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would seem to want a `left join`:

```
select od.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by od.[order] order by line) = 1
             then ot.value
        end) as value
from orderdetails od left join
     ordertotals ot
     on od.[order] = ot.[order]
order by od.[order], od.line;
```

I'm not sure why you would want `value` on only one line, but this should achieve that goal.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A.[Order],
       CASE
         WHEN Row_number()
                OVER(
                  PARTITION BY A.[ORDER]
                  ORDER BY A.[ORDER]) = 1 THEN VALUE
         ELSE NULL
       END AS VALUE,
       B.[Line Description]
FROM   TABLE1 A
       LEFT JOIN Table2 B
              ON A.[Order] = B.[Order]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
            select 
            od.Order,
            od.Line ,
            od.Description,
            ot.Value

            from
            OrderTotals OT 
            join Orderdetails OD on OT.order=od.order
```

if you have any query please let us know

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM    
    Orderdetails X LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            OrderTotals A INNER JOIN
            (SELECT OD.Order, MIN(OD.Line) MinLine FROM Orderdetails OD GROUP BY OD.Order) B ON A.Order = B.Order

    ) Y ON X.Order = Y.Order AND X.Line = Y.MinLine
```